# Is toilet paper singular?

Tags: grammar

> There's a shortage of toilet paper. People who hoarded them/it are the
>   reason.

Do we use it or them? I think it's "it", but it sounds wrong. I think "them" sounds better, but I have no idea if the rules are malleable or extremely strict on this. Is there any good reference that can sort out this uncertainty?

Answer (score 1):

There is some flexibility,

But the "rules" say that paper is usually an uncountable noun, and here it is certainly being used as an uncountable noun. Uncountable nouns are singular, so you must use "it"

It is fine to say

> ... rolls of toilet paper... People who hoarded them.

Comment: Toilet paper is not uncountable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKC67l5bYhA

Comment: @jsejcksn It may not be _technically_ uncountable, but it is certainly _grammatically_ uncountable.

Comment: It didn't read as a joke to you guys?

Comment: I guess sarcasm *is* hard on the internet.